Qual é a diferença entre Material e MaterialApp?
Estou a estudar Flutter e vi que o Flutter usa a ferramenta Material Design, e já vi exemplos em que se usa a classe Material e outros em que se usa a classe MaterialApp.
Material(
    child: Column(
        children: [
            MyAppBar( 
...


MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
...

Qual é a diferença entre a classe Material e a classe MaterialApp?

Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51061147/1817673

Material
Material é uma classe genérica do Material Design que geralmente encapsula componentes filhos. Seu propósito é fornecer aos componentes filhos alguns comportamentos ou formatos que são passados a sí.
Por exemplo: o componente Image.asset não possui uma propriedade shape, então se eu quiser que essa imagem tenha borda arredondada, eu posso utilizar o Material como componente pai e usar sua propriedade shape, passando assim seu formato para o componente filho também.
Código do exemplo:
Material(
  child: Image.file(
    "path_da_imagem",
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
  borderRadius:
    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(45.0)),
),


Material App
MaterialApp é uma classe de convenção para iniciar aplicações, ela encapsula diversos Widgets para facilitar o início do desenvolvimento sem muito código boilerplate, configurando automaticamente funcionalidades específicas do Material Design.
Ela também fornece a opção de algumas configurações opcionais como o uso de rotas nomeadas na aplicação, comportamento do banner de debug, temas, entre outros.
Exemplo de uso:
const MaterialApp(
  title: 'Material App',
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Hello World'),
    ),
  ),
)


Conclusão
Existe uma grande diferença entre a classe Material e a classe MaterialApp, a primeira sendo usada como uma classe genérica para criar um Widget do tipo Material e lhe prover algumas características e a segunda sendo uma classe de convenção, que facilita a inicialização da aplicação.
As funcionalidades das 2 são muito distintas e casos de uso para cada também.

Quer dizer que eu poderia utilizar no atributo home: o código acima de Material em vez do Scaffold?

Sim e não.... Sim, você pode usar o Material ao invés do Scaffold no atributo home... Porém, será difícil você atingir o mesmo resultado, porque como o MaterialApp, o Scaffold é uma classe de convenção, ela ajuda a juntar varias necessidades que telas comuns tem em um Widget com vários atributos nullables, então reproduzir o comportamento do Scaffold é possível, porém demandará muita implementação em cima do Material e o uso de outros Widgets filhos.

Então a classe Material seria utilizada em algum dos Widget's dentro do Scaffold, por exemplo?

isso, o Material pode ser utilizado como um widget, ele pode ter seu formato definido através de um shape e ter filhos que irão compor um layout, porém é muito mais abstrato que outros widgets prontos do flutter, então em teoria, você pode chegar ao mesmo resultado de um outro Widget como um  Scaffold por exemplo, porém isso irá requerir bastante implementação uma vez que você não estará utilizando a implementação pronta por trás do Widget Scaffold, você estaria basicamente "reinventando a roda".
